# request query using jsom for project server (ps.js) another user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom, credentials

request query using JSOM for project server (ps.js) another user

I need request a query using another user, no my current user this is possible?
I'm using JSOM with ps.js for project server 2013

Using CSOM (c#) I need only change my credentials in my context, like this

```
var c = new NetworkCredentials(user, pass);
context.Credentials = c;
```

but, on JSOM I don't see anything with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not impersonate or elevate using JSOM, instead you would need to call a CSOM service that can do the impersonation, fetches the information and then returns it.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. I solved my problem using CSOM.